# No module named kivy.tools.packaging.pyinstaller_hooks

Tags: python, pyinstaller, kivy

I'm following [Kivy's Windows-packaging guide](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-windows.html).
I'm at the last step, [building the spec](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-windows.html#build-the-spec), and I get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named kivy.tools.packaging.pyinstaller_hooks
```

I'm using Python 2.7.5, the [Kivy 1.7.2 for Windows](http://kivy.googlecode.com/files/Kivy-1.7.2-w32.zip), and the [PyInstaller 2.1](https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/P/PyInstaller/PyInstaller-2.1.zip).
All previous steps of the guide work.
For this guide, I'm packaging up my Pong game, which I made using Kivy's [Pong game tutorial](http://kivy.org/docs/tutorials/pong.html).
I stopped the tutorial at the point where the ball is only bouncing around, but it's technically a working program using Kivy, so it should be good enough to practice packaging.

I've looked at [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/embed/?place=forum/kivy-users&hidesubject=true&hideforumtitle=true&showsearch=true&showpopout=true&parenturl=http%3A%2F%2Fkivy.org%2F%23#!searchin/kivy-users/packaging.pyinstaller_hooks/kivy-users/sjocv0ZrsAw/3YzOXQ_DqfIJ) in the Kivy support area, and it doesn't help.
(The files listed in that post as being missing, are present in my Kivy download.)

**Where do I find the module in the error message, and how to I tell PyInstaller where to find it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Running `kivy.bat` before running `pyinstaller.py` will fix the error.*

This batch file sets the appropriate paths, so that pyinstaller knows where to find Kivy.
This step is listed in the tutorial; It is essential that no steps are missed.

Answer (score 3):

If your OS is Ubuntu and you installed kivy via the ppa-repository, you should do `sudo apt install kivy-tools`.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this to the top of your .spec file:

```
import kivy
```

If that generates an error when you run pyinstaller, you probably haven't setup your environment correctly.

Specifically, you're probably using a pyinstaller from C:\Python\ instead of C:\blah\Kivy\bin...

The easiest way to get this to work is to install an MSYS shell, and do it like this:

```
. /c/blah/kivyenv.sh
pip install pyinstaller
pyinstaller main.spec
```

I've only had grief with the default terminal (ie. non MSYS), so if you're using that I'm afraid I'm got no idea.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using the default terminal. :|

Comment: I tried using the . /c/blah/kivyenv.sh and it will say no such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

If your OS is ubuntu, go to kivy git repository

[kivy tools/packaging](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/tree/master/kivy/tools/packaging)

and copy/past files to this directory

> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/tools/packaging/